# Prevent PHP from removing XML tags

Tags: php, html, xml

I want the XML users are entering in HTML form as is in PHP with all elements/tags, I tried PHP's Simple XML but it's removing all tags from XML and just showing me the content/value in those XML tags for example:

`<tag>Hello</tag>`

User input this in HTML form and I only get Hello, but I need whole code.

**Edit:**

Another example XML code:

```
<Orders>
<Order>
  <email>myemail@gmail.com</email>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <Product_Id>242</Product_Id>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Product_Id>425</Product_Id>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Order>
<Order>
  <email>youremail@gmail.com</email>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <Product_Id>657</Product_Id>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Product_Id>789</Product_Id>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

PHP Code:

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 30px;">
    <form action="" method="post" id="xml-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="xml-text" style="line-height: 40px; font-size: 20px">XML Code:</label>
        <br>
        <textarea id="xml-text" name="xml-text" rows="30" cols="150" style="font-size: .8rem; letter-spacing: 1px; padding: 10px; line-height: 1.5; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input id="xml-sumbit" name="xml-sumbit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: white; border-color: black;">
    </form>
</div>

<span id="test"></span>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['xml-sumbit']) && !empty($_POST["xml-text"])) {
  header('Content-Type: text/plain');
  print_r(explode("<Order>", $_POST["xml-text"]));
}
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: You need to escape the output, your browser is interpreting `<tag>` as HTML.

Comment: You are almost certainly being misled by the way you are debugging your code. If you do _nothing_, PHP will leave the XML as is; if you parse it with SimpleXML, it will turn into an object that lets you access it, _and still get back the original XML_.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I add another example code, please check.

Comment: @AlexHowansky how do I escape the output?

Comment: @IMSoP so if I echo or print_r out without parsing it with SimpleXML it is showing this ```myemail@gmail.com 242 425 youremail@gmail.com 657 789```

Comment: @MusabShakeel Your browser will assume that it's HTML unless you tell it otherwise. Click "View Source" in your browser, use htmlspecialchars(), send a content type of text/plain, view it with something other than a web browser, ...

Comment: @IMSoP after adding ```header('Content-Type: text/plain');``` it's outputting the whole HTML with XML, which is good but I can't explode() the XML, like I want the first <Order> XML code, so I need to explode the Order but it's not working, explode is considering whole XML as a one thing and can't exploding it.

Comment: Please share more details - without seeing the code you are using, it's impossible to tell you where it goes wrong and what you have to change

Comment: @NicoHaase I edited my question by adding php code, please check

Comment: 1. explode() using text/plain: Explodes properly but also showing HTML form with it
2. explode() using htmlspecialchars: Don't explode properly but showing only XML

One explodes but shows HTML, another one doesn't explode but remove HTML. So how to combine the power of both to remove HTML and explode properly.

Comment: What's the expected output for that code? What have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: Firstly, text/plain is a way of you *debugging* your code; it's not changing what your code *does*. Secondly, have you looked at [the SimpleXML usage examples in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)? I'm willing to bet something in there is what you want, not explode().

Comment: @NicoHaase I recently comment that
1. explode() using text/plain: Explodes properly but also showing HTML form with it 
2. explode() using htmlspecialchars: Don't explode properly but showing XML

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing. Don't use the comment section for important stuff